# How to add unlimited markers on click - google maps api

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm developing an application using Google Maps API.
I'm trying to add a marker where the user press on the map and to draw a line between markers that the user have created.

I'v tried to add the method SetOnMapClickListener but every time I run my application in the virtual device it's immediately crushes.
I've also tried to locate the method in OnCreate method and in OnMapReady, but this is not working either.
I succeeded to add new markers but only by writing them...

On some tutorials that I've found I saw that they assign the google map object with mapFragment.getMap(), but I don't have this method.
Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.user.testmap;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                double lit = latLng.latitude;
                double lon = latLng.longitude;
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lit, lon)));

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(20, 5)));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(20, 5)));

    }

}
```

Comment: May you display your code please? You have to bring a mimimun of effort when you ask your question.

Comment: sorry, I'm new here, I've edited the post.

Comment: Add the logcat error to your post. Stack trace will point to the failure

Answer (score 0):

try to remove your `mMap.setOnMapClickListener` in `onCreate()` then `implements` the `GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener`

like this.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private ArrayList<Marker> arrMarkerList;
    private ArrayList<Polyline> arrPolylineList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
        arrMarkerList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrPolylineList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
        double lit = latLng.latitude;
        double lon = latLng.longitude;
        arrMarkerList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lit, lon))));

        // Removing the existing polyline to draw a new.
        for (Polyline polyline : arrPolylineList) {
            polyline.remove();
        }

        if (arrMarkerList.size() > 1) {
            PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
            for (Marker marker : arrMarkerList) {
                polylineOptions.add(marker.getPosition());
            }
            arrPolylineList.add(mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ToharPingley I edited my answer. You can use a `Polyline` to draw a lines between those points. Glad to help you. can you please mark my answer as accepted. Thanks.